# How to search for an object in HashSet?

Tags: java, class, contains, hashset

In my Java program, the class `GraphPoint` describes points of a combinatorial structure using two coordinates *m* and *n* which are its only variables. I want to create an unordered set of such points:

```
Set<GraphPoint> collection = new HashSet<>();
```

Now I want to know whether `collection` contains a point with the given coordinates. What would be the fastest way to code this?

Comment: `collection.contains(new GraphPoint(m, n))`?

Comment: @Ryan Assuming the class implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2):

If the `GraphPoint` class implements `hashCode` and `equals` correctly, then use `contains` method:

```
collection.contains(new GraphPoint(m,n))
```

Per the [JavaDoc for the HashSet contains() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) will test equality using the `equals` method before returning true. Specifically:

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

For the sake of completeness, and assuming that your `GraphPoint` class acts exactly like a `Point`, you can implement `hashCode` and `equals` as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = m;
    result = 31 * result + n;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof GraphPoint)) return false;
    final GraphPoint that = (GraphPoint) other;
    return this.m == that.m && this.n == that.n;
}
```

Recommended reading: [Effective Java: Equals and HashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

*Also, thanks to @Federico_Peralta_Schaffner and @shmosel for the feedback on my previous answer*

Comment: Is it `x` and `y` or `m` and `n`?

Comment: But you have `x` and `y` in `hashCode()`.

Comment: fixed :) Thanks again for the feedback!